# CraftCMS + GraphQL - orderBy Random?

Tags: graphql, headless, vue

I'm currently building my first JAM stack app using Nuxt as my front-end framework and Craft as my headless CMS. I'm leveraging Apollo as my GraphQL interface client. I have it pulling data back just fine, but I want to shuffle the output to always be random. I know I could do this in a typical twig query with `.orderBy('RAND()')` but I need a way to shuffle that with my GraphQL endpoint.

I know I can do this on the frontend by shuffling my `<li>`s or something, but would love for this to be more performant if I can help it.

I've tried a few variations of the below but can't seem to get it to work. Is this possible?

```
apollo: {
  entries: {
    query: stories,
    prefetch: true,
    variables: {
       "section": ["stories"],
       "orderBy": "RAND()"
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: This feels like it should work. Are you sure you are not hitting cached results?

Comment: Hey Oli. Well I know RAND() is a PHP function. Maybe this isn't a Craft CMS question and more of an Apollo question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RAND()` is the correct way to do this. (At least, it works in 3.5). One catch is that GraphQL queries are [cached by default](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#enablegraphqlcaching), so your results will always be returned in the same random order until your cache is invalidated. If you're using Nuxt with a static target, your entries will be displayed in the same order until the cache is expired *and* your app is regenerated.

Example of a working query:

```
{
  entries(section: "posts", orderBy:"RAND()") {
    title
    id
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this stopped working after a recent update. Now I get "Illegal value for `orderBy` argument: `RAND()`".

Comment: It seems to work with `random()` now.